# Spring webflux 5.2.3 bodyToMono called after empty Mono in onStatus

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I've created a WebClient to make a get request, and to specifically handle the 404 error I'm using the onStatus method as shown in the snippet below.

```
 client.get()
                .uri(someUrl)
                .headers(someHeaders)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND), r -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(MyJsonResponse.class)
```

When I get a 404 in the response, my expectation is that it should return an empty mono, however, it calls subsequent body to mono as well and tries to parse the response, which, ideally it should not do. Any suggestions ?

Comment: by default Mono#empty will `Create a Mono that completes without emitting any item.` meaning that it will complete and then execution will continue. So as in your case go to `bodyToMono` if you wish to just ignore, you should do something like `switchIfEmpty` and there continue pick up with what you want to do, or return an error and use `onErrorContinue`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Toerktumlare. It looks like something changed in the new version, it used to work as expected when the code was on Spring-webflux 5.0.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#onStatus-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.Function-) of the `onStatus` method recommends using `onErrorResume` or `filter` for your use case:

> To ignore an error response completely, and propagate neither response nor error, use a filter, or add onErrorResume downstream, for example:

```java
 webClient.get()
     .uri("https://example.com/account/123")
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(Account.class)
     .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
          ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 404 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex));
```

It was indeed a behavior change in Spring not so long ago. Related discussion: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24736

Answer (score 0):

by default [Mono#empty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#empty--) will:

`Create a Mono that completes without emitting any item.`

meaning that it will complete and then execution will continue. So as in your case go to `bodyToMono`. if you wish to just ignore, you should do something like `switchIfEmpty` and there continue pick up with what you want to do, or return an `Mono#error` and use `onErrorContinue`